# How to get user in Laravel by XSRF-TOKEN cookie?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I can't get the authenticated user in Laravel app. I have this codes:

**config/auth.php**

```php
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'sanctum',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'members',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'members' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' =>  Domain\Customer\Models\Member::class,
        ]
    ],
];
```

**config/sanctum.php**

```php
return [
    'stateful' => // ...
    'guard' => null,
    'expiration' => null,
    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],
];
```

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::prefix('auth')->group(function ($router) {
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'loginAsMember']);
    // ...
});
Route::middleware('lang')->group(function ($router) {
    // ...

    Route::prefix('{locale}')->group(function () {
        Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
            Route::get('webshop/basket', [PublicBasketController::class, 'show'])->name(RouteName::BASKET);
        });
    });

    // ...
});
```

I have an Authenticate middleware where I try to catch the user and if it's not logged in I redirect to the custom login url.

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route(RouteName::LOGIN, ['local' => App::getLocale()]);
        }
    }
}
```

In here if I `dd(Auth::user())` it receives null.

But if I `dd($request)` I see this:

```
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#46 ▼
    #parameters: array:4 [ ▼
      "XSRF-TOKEN" => "MbJcRadlrAJ2mDhECvWwMFyIe0fyqrQUO83K2U1K"
      "laravel_session" => "mqWuCqTRD074TOvOPMGRfIIgP0jxKLyoD8VyyWCS"
    ]
  }
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#49 ▼
    #headers: array:13 [▼
      "cookie" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "_ga=... ▶"
      ]
      "accept-language" => array:1 [▶]
      "accept-encoding" => array:1 [▶]
      "referer" => array:1 [▶]
      "accept" => array:1 [▶]
      "user-agent" => array:1 [▶]
      "upgrade-insecure-requests" => array:1 [▶]
      "cache-control" => array:1 [▶]
      "pragma" => array:1 [▶]
      "connection" => array:1 [▶]
      "host" => array:1 [▶]
      "content-length" => array:1 [▶]
      "content-type" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
    #cacheControl: array:1 [▼
      "no-cache" => true
    ]
  }
```

So there is an valid XSRF-TOKEN cookie, but Laravel did not identify the user.

How can I get user by XSRF-TOKEN cookie?

Comment: _"How can I get user by XSRF-TOKEN cookie?"_ - who says you actually could? As far as I understand it, that token doesn't include any user information - it is a random token, that gets stored into the user session, and can then be compared against the value in the session, when the request that needs "protection" is made. But its point is not to authenticate the user.

Comment: If anything, `laravel_session` is what should allow you to pick up the current user's session again, and then it should find the information that they already authenticated, in there.

Comment: do you want to use laravel as complete website, or SPA or just backend ? for the later 2 , you can move your routes to routes/api.php and for user authentication, you can use build in sanctum login and authorization token

Comment: @CBroe alright, I understand XSRF-TOKEN is NOT for identify the user. Anyway, in the request I see the `laravel_session` cookie too, and still the `Auth::user()` is null.

Comment: @Win I have a VueJS login component with a service class. The service class made an Axios post request where I receive back user's data. So the user can log in. After this the user is redirected to the home page. And that is a simple Laravel website. And there the `Auth::user()` is null, like in the question.

Comment: after login, you do receive token , correct ? use that to authorize your way to access your api routes, dont forget to add middleware('auth:sanctum') where routes need restricted access , read here more https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#protecting-routes

Comment: @Win correct. But I want to use the received token on `web.php` routes, not on `api.php` and these sites ar NOT SPA, but regulare websites. I tried to use `Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')` too, still null in `Auth::user()`

Comment: try this = https://youtu.be/_NevyJBb8fQ

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dd($request->user)` or `dd(auth('sanctum')->user()`.

Comment: Thanks your fast answer! I tried and both are null.